# Show All Posts Insert Edit Link

Tags: query, tinymce

When I click to insert/edit link in the tinyMCE rich editor for a post, then click "Or link to existing content", it shows only posts that are live and published.  Is there a way to get the list that is searched to also include future and draft posts?  I need to do this without modifying any core files, is there a hook I can tap into to modify the called query?

Comment: If you publish a post with a link to an unpublished post in it you will generate 404s. I think that is the logic behind tinyMCE code. I will peek at that code though and see if there is a way to change it (without editing core files).

Comment: Yeah, I understand why they have it that way.  We launch a lot of articles around a magazine issue, and it all goes live on one day

Comment: Actually, it would be useful for me too and for the same reason, so I am looking into it. It would make our editors happy. So far, I have not solved it though.

Answer (score 1):

See if this doesn't do it:

First, the callback for that Ajax search (the `wp_link_query` method in `wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php`) suppresses the normal filters. We have to turn them back on for this particular query.

```
function undo_suppress($qry) {
  global $_POST;
  if (isset($_POST['action']) && 'wp-link-ajax' == $_POST['action']) {
    $qry->set('suppress_filters',false);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','undo_suppress');
```

Now we can use the `posts_where` filter to enable searches across 'future' posts.

```
function search_future_editor_links($where) {
  global $_POST;
  if (isset($_POST['action']) && 'wp-link-ajax' == $_POST['action']) {
    $where = ' AND wp_posts.post_type IN ("post","page","attachment") AND wp_posts.post_status IN ("publish","future") ';
  }
  return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where','search_future_editor_links');
```

You could add "drafts" to that last `IN` if you wanted to search those too.